# Why my app docker is not getting connected to my database docker?

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, containers

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    api:
        image: nefcanto/dotnet-dev
        restart: always
        container_name: DotNetApi
        working_dir: /Api
        environment: 
            - HolismProjectsRoot=/HolismDotNet
        volumes: 
            - /HolismDotNet/Framework:/HolismDotNet/Framework
            - /HolismDotNet/Api:/HolismDotNet/Api
            - .:/Api
        ports: 
            - "5000:5000"
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            dotnet build
            && dotnet Api/bin/Holism.Geo.Api.dll
            "
        depends_on: 
            - "sql"
    sql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        restart: always
        container_name: Sql
        volumes:
            - ./Database:/var/opt/mssql
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=lksU2o412f7tBj58t07B
            - MSSQL_PID=Express
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            tail -f /dev/null
            "
```

As you can see I'm developing `.NET Core` app and I have created two containers.
Here is the connection string that my app uses:

```
data source=sql,1433; initial catalog=Geo; user id=sa; password=password_here
```

I tested with both `sql` and `Sql`. But my app container does not see my db container.

I'm on linux, and I can connect to my database using interactive shell.

```
docker exec -it DotNetApi sh -c
# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P password_here
> select newid();
> go;
                                    
------------------------------------
2FCD5E38-B526-4B76-AB74-A8DF9971D103

(1 rows affected)
```

What should I do?

Comment: The name of the server to communicate should be the name of the service. In this case you should try to replace `localhost` with `sql`

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that Docker only maps container_name:dynamic_Ip on user created networks.

Apparently, you are using the default bridge network, so your app won't be able to find sql or Sql or whatever.

You have two different ways of solving this:

1. `docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network` and run those containers on that network.
2. When running the containers, you must --link them, as the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) indicates.